# MySQL Date Variables and normal variables

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables

I have from my mysql database:

```
$event_date -> (mysql query get database from events) 2013-10-09
```

In a variable I have

```
$var_date = "2013-10-09"

if ($event_date == $var_date) {
bla bla (but this doesn't work)
}
```

I remember having this problem with another website but I don't remember. The data query from the database is not equal to a normal variable even if it contains the same thing. How can I make it to like convert to the same format?

Thank you world.

EDIT: When I echo them, they are exactly the same.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($event_date);var_dump($var_date);`? EDIT: I'm not sure whether that's your actual code, but `$var_date = 2013-10-09` is invalid and should throw a fatal error.

Comment: Are you missing quotes around `$var_date` definition?  The way it is written now, `$var_date` would hold an integer value of `1994`.

Comment: I forgot my quotes, When I echo them both, they are exactly the same, but I don't know why it doesn't work, none of any posts work

Comment: I fixed it, I did a mistake in the code that's why

Answer (score 2):

```
$var_date = "2013-10-09";

if (trim($event_date) == trim($var_date)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I use for comparing dates because they can come in so many different formats, like with year first or year last or two-digit years.  It returns 0 for the same date/time, -1 for if $a is less than $b, and 1 if $b is less than $a.

```
function compareDates($a, $b) {
  if(!is_int($a) && !ctype_digit($a)) {
    $a = strtotime($a);
  }
  if(!is_int($b) && !ctype_digit($b)) {
    $b = strtotime($b);
  }
  if($a > $b) {
    return 1;
  }
  if($a < $b) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```